# Reflection Java

Tags: runtime, java, рефлексия

прочитал , что главным отличием **Reflection** от **RTTI** является то, что *.class* в первом случае доступен компилятору, а во втором - интерпретатору(на стадии выполнения). Пусть я получаю файл по сокету, посредством сериализации, как в этом случае можно получить *.class* ?

Comment: Где вы это прочитали? И что значит доступен .class и получить .class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ника, .class должен уже быть, иначе десериализовать не получится.

Можно .class по сокету передать сначала, подгрузить его classLoader'ом в jvm, а вот потом передать сериализованный объект. Зная класс его можно будет загружать.

Нашёл [пример загрузки классов из указанной папки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219829/method-to-dynamically-load-java-class-files):

```
// Create a File object on the root of the directory containing the class file
File file = new File("c:\\myclasses\\");

try {
    // Convert File to a URL
    URL url = file.toURL();          // file:/c:/myclasses/
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

    // Create a new class loader with the directory
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    // Load in the class; MyClass.class should be located in
    // the directory file:/c:/myclasses/com/mycompany
    Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.MyClass");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
```

Суть в том, чтобы был ClassLoader у которого в class path указанна директория, с загруженными файлами (их можно туда скидывать после загрузки по сокету). Inmamory сложней будет, придётся наверное самостоятельно имплементацию ClassLoader'а делать.

Comment: что значит Inmamory ?

Comment: Имел в веду, если захочется не сохранять на диск, а грузить прямо из полученного из сокета массива байт (в памяти).

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov In memory загрузка класса не требует своего *ClassLoader**. Достаточно использовать *ObjectStream* - класс, который оборачивает класс потока сокета!

Comment: Так вы класс или объект грузить хотите?